# QT resource is missing

Tags: c++, qt, resourcedictionary

I made a simple QT application that display a gif image only. Althought I created a qrc file to store my gif image and icon. Then I set icon for the widget using Qt creator. Then I load gif using following code:

```
Welcome::Welcome(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Welcome)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMovie *movie = new QMovie(":/icon/rc/login.gif");
    movie->scaledSize();
    ui->label->setMovie(movie);
    movie->start();
}
```

I tried to run this in QT Creator and everything is fine.

[image: Normal picture]

Then, I try to run it directly (I copy all neccessary libraries to the folder offcourse) but it is missing both gif and icon image.

[image: Missing image picture]

Please help me to solve this. I appreciate your answer. Thanks

This is my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QSSHTool
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    welcome.cpp

HEADERS  += welcome.h

FORMS    += welcome.ui

RESOURCES += \
    qsshresource.qrc
```

Comment: This issue is most probably related to the compilation of your program, your c++ code seems ok. Can you edit your question and post your .pro file ?

Comment: I added .pro file content. After some searching, people tell me that I should copy qgif.dll and put next to exe file. I did it but the status isn't changed

Comment: Where you got this dll from? Plugins folder? If so try to copy it to plugins folder in your application retaining the original folder structure with subfolders like plugins/images/qtgif.dll or similar

Comment: And should add one more line in .pro file as my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Firstly, add this line into .pro file to allow gif plugin to be loaded

```
QTPLUGIN += gif
```

Then, when deploying your application, beside neccessary libraries, copy the qgif.dll to directory:

```
<executable_dir>/plugins/imageformats/qgif.dll
```

And it is done :) Hope it can help someone.

Comment: Instead of copying manually the plugin, you could use macdeployqt or windeployqt tool (depending on your platform) to do this task automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simple! I have the same problem!
For me i just clicked on Qt Menu->Build->Run qmake.
After this i clicked on Qt Menu->Build->Build Project "..." Ctrl + B
It works for me...

Comment: It is OK if we run apps from QtCreator, however, I want to bring apps to another machine that didn't have QtCreator and the issue occured